# Chart.js on Angular with @types/chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, angular7

I am trying to implement Chart.js on my Angular project with version 7.1.4.

However, I cannot initialize any graphs in all means. Is there any lines that I have missed?

**Package used:**

> **chart.js**: npm install chart.js --save
>
> **@types/chart.js**: npm install @types/chart.js --save

**HTML side:**

```
<canvas #canvas id="chart">{{ chart }}</canvas>
```

**Component Side:**

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
chart: Chart;

var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("rohsProductSummaryChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,  //<-- confirmed with correct structure
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        display: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        display: true
                    }],
                }
            }
  });
```

How can I generate with no exceptions?
Thank you.

Comment: reproduce this issue in stackblitz and show us link here

Comment: make sure the data is passed at the moment the chart is drawn on the page and not after, you can build/fetch your dataset in ngOnInit, have it set a variable for instance canRender = true once it's done, and in your canvas tag add *ngIf="canRender" that tells the canvas to draw the moment your dataset is confirmed built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding a div tag covering the canvas tag.

```
<div>
<canvas #canvas id="chart">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

Thanks.